# htaccess rewriting url messes up some files

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using htaccess to rewrite urls that only include a username to a url that would link to the profile page

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lrBoot/profile.php?username=$1
```

Now all the files in the same directory as this htaccess file work fine (open the page instead of assuming its a profile username), for example,

> www.example.com/lrBoot/index.php

opens the index.php page.

But, when I try to link to a file that's in a directory, it treats it like a profile name and it doesn't open the file. For example, in the same directory as the htaccess file, I have a directory called universities and within it I have a file called classes.php, when I use href="universities/classes.php" the url becomes

> www.example.com/lrBootInclude/universities/classes.php

How can I fix this so that whenever the user enters the profile url:

> www.example.com/lrBootInclude/alex

It redirects to:

> www.example.com/lrBootInclude/profile.php?username=alex

But when they press on the link in my index.php file it opens the page:

> www.example.com/lrBootInclude/universities/classes.php

Comment: This is just a guess, but have you tried setting the urls as absolute paths from the web root? Instead of href="universities/classes.php" does it work if you do "/IrBootInclude/universities/classes.php"?

Comment: @StevenJeffries, that worked for the most part, but I ran into another problem. I have images stored in a directory inside the main directory and whenever I want the image to be displayed on the index.php page, it works fine because the path is just /images/imageName.png, but when im in the universities/classes.php page, the image does not show and that is because the directory is not the same, it works if I do ../images/imageName.png, I tried using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] so that the address is always the same, but that didn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: The !-f and !-d part of the condition means "if this doesn't point to a file and this doesn't point to a directory". If your images aren't being found, then that just means that your url pointing to them is incorrect. Look at what $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] prints out and see if that helps to get you correct urls.